# Why in C and C++ dynamically allocated objects are unnamed?

Tags: c++, c, object, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

In C and C++ dynamically allocated objects are **natively** created and managed indirectly through pointers and therefore remain unnamed, unlike automatically and statically allocated objects which are **natively** created and can be managed directly with names. For example, considering an `int` variable C++, we have

For dynamic allocation:

```
int* p = new int;
```

For automatic allocation:

```
int i;   // (in a block)
```

For static allocation:

```
int j;   // (in the global namespace)

static int k;   // (in a block)
```

What's the technical reason for this asymmetry of approaches in storage allocation between static and automatic versus the dynamic case?

As different comments below note, it's actually possible in C++ (but not in C) to use a reference variable and bind it to a dynamically allocated object so that it will be **afterwards** possible to use it directly with a name.

*But this is not the point of my question*. I'm not interested in if and how it's possible to circumvent the native approach of the language and give names to dynamically allocated objects. I would just like to understand the technical reason why the designers of the language opted for **native** different approaches (names for static and automatic vs unnamed for dynamic) regarding the memory allocations of objects.

Comment: If a dynamic object had a name, it wouldn't be dynamic.

Comment: Because the heap knows nothing about what is stored there, It can be anything. Same goes for the stack, but the language does naming management.

Comment: Why *would* they be named?

Comment: @dbush Well, you could have allocated a bunch of bytes and call it "Bob".

Comment: Because that's how C++ works.

Comment: FWIW, `std::vector<some_type> some_name;` gives a dynamic object a name. RAII FTW

Comment: No technical reason. But this is the way these languages are specified and there is not enough rationale to specify it otherwise.

Comment: `int* p = new int{7}; int& name_of_dynamic_object = *p;`

Comment: The concept of identifiers and variable names does not exist at run time. The number, identify and lifetime of dynamically allocated objects are by definition only known at run time, so trying to name them doesn't make sense. But if you want, you can introduce the concept by putting our dynamically allocated objects in a `std::map<std::string, T>`.

Comment: To be clear, you are asking why in the example `int* p = new int;`, there is no regular variable name associated with the int object `p[0]`?

Comment: Can you give an example of a language where dynamically allocated objects are named?

Comment: @NathanOliver ???  I'd say logically that gives the *container* a name, just like `int x;` gives the name `x` to an `int`.  I wouldn't say that `vector<>` itself is dynamic - from that isolated line, it's either static or automatic.

Comment: Imho your premise is strictly speaking wrong: "In C and C++ dynamically allocated objects are created and managed exclusively through pointers". Once you realize that you can use other ways than pointers, you can also give them names: `int& name_for_a_dynamic_object = *p;`. There is no need to name them, but if you like you can

Comment: @Kevin: Every “scripting” language.

Comment: @EricPostpischil which presumably use pointers for dynamic allocation and hide it behind syntax.

Comment: @Kevin The question is about the "programmer perspective" I guess

Comment: @Kevin: So? The object nonetheless has a name. The fact that the language uses pointers in its implementation is irrelevant—the name exists and is not made to not exist by the use of pointers. (Incidentally, how do you think C returns structure objects from functions? You cannot return a kibibyte structure in registers. The caller passes a pointer to it. The programmer never sees a pointer in the source code, but it is there.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil Judging by the OP's question they don't seem to think that a pointer is "good enough". I would say that something is "named", at least in the way the OP means, if you can't rebind that name to something else. A value or reference variable in C++ fits that, but a pointer does not and neither does any variable in Python for example. Maybe I'm just being pedantic.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818: yes you are correct, the trick works in C++. But it doesn't in C, where there aren't references, so it's not possible to bind an alias to the originally unnamed object. Anyway this is not the point of my question. I'm not interested in if and how I can circumvent the native approach of the language and give names to dynamically allocated objects. I would just like to understand the reason why the designers of the language opted for **native** different approaches (names for static and automatic vs unnamed for dynamic) regarding the memory allocations of objects.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish: I would just like to understand the reason why the designers of the language opted for **native** different approaches (names for static and automatic vs unnamed for dynamic) regarding the memory allocations of objects.

Comment: @disquisitiones thats the reason why questions should not be tagged with two different languages. And I am not just nitpicking here, I am certain that the reasons why the language is like it is is a completely different story for C and C++

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818: I suspect quite the opposite, I think that C++ is following C in the **native** approach for the usual compatibility reasons and I believe that the real answer to my question lies actually in the history of C design. Of course C++ added more functionality like references that incidentally would allow the binding of a name to a dynamically allocated object. But as I said, I'm not interested in this, rather I'm interested in understanding the reason behind the **native** approach of the 2 languages regarding the memory allocation.

Comment: I propose the reopening of the question after having edited it for clarifying and focusing the point addressed, after having considered the observations in the comments received.

Comment: @disquisitiones Can you give an example of what you think defining a named dynamic object might look like? In particular where having a dynamic object would actually be useful (unlike a simple `new int`).

Comment: Yes of course. I think that in general this can illustrate the idea: `dynamic int i;` where _dynamic_ would be a storage class specifier as for example _static_ is. This means that you declare an int and that its lifetime is manually controlled. A `delete &i;` would complete the syntax for actually ending the lifetime of the object. When in need of passing the address of the object to other scopes (typical usage of dynamic allocation, detached from the scope expiration lifetime policy) you do it as usual. For example you could return it from a function that created the object with `return &i;`

Answer (score 3):

Variable names are part of the source code and therefore fixed at compile time; they can’t be created at run time.  In fact, if you’ve stripped debug information from your executable, they likely don’t even *exist* at run time.

Dynamically allocated objects exist only at run time, since that is when they are created.  Therefore there is no way to name them with variable names, because there is no source code or IDE available at run time.  (It might be possible for a debugger to assign a name to a dynamically allocated object after pausing the program at a breakpoint, but of course most of the time programs run without a debugger)

Comment: You say that "Dynamically allocated objects exist only at run time". But isn't this also true for example for automatically allocated objects? Stack frames (and automatic objects within them) are created and obliterated in memory as functions are called and return during run time.

Comment: I guess what I was trying to get across is that there is a 1:1 relationship between variable-names and objects, either on a global level or on a per-function-call level, and that is what makes variable naming possible.  Eg consider a (non-recursive) function that allocates a random number of objects.  I don’t think it’s possible to give those objects names at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

Who says dynamic objects can't have names?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int &i = *(new int);
    i = 5;
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
    delete &i;   // no more leak
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If that leaks memory, `i` is not the object.

Comment: That's quite clever.

Comment: But this doesn't work in C, where there aren't references, so it's not possible to bind an alias to the originally unnamed object. Anyway this is not the point of my question. I'm not interested in if and how I can circumvent the native approach of the language and give names to dynamically allocated objects. I would just like to understand which is the technical reason why the designers of the language opted for **native** different approaches (names for static and automatic vs unnamed for dynamic) regarding the memory allocations of objects.

Answer (score 2):

1. Because the designers of the languages decided so (possibly by not considering such choice in the first place).
2. Because there is no need for a name.
3. Because such name would not be useful.

Comment: But then if valid, why points 2. and 3. should not be applicable uniformly to all the storage allocation tipologies? If names are not needed nor useful, why to have them for static and automatic allocation?